# Change visible rectangle of content in ContentControl

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, custom-controls

In WPF I have `ContentControl` that has limited size (lets say 100x30). A `Content` of this `ContentControl` is a `Label` of size 200x30 so the whole `Label` cannot be visible within the `ContentControl`.

How can I programatically set which area of the `Label` is visible in `ContentControl` ? The visible area (rectangle) of the content may change over time. Can I do this without using `ScrollViewer` (just to set visible clip) ?

EDIT: Well then, I am not even able to do it using `ScrollViewer` so any advice on that would be appriciated as well

Answer (score 1):

You can place your label on canvas and move it using Canvas.Left property.

Small example where label's position is adjusted using binding to a slider Value property.

```
<ContentControl Width="100" Height="30">
  <Canvas ClipToBounds="True">
    <Label Canvas.Left="{Binding ElementName=mySlider, Path=Value}" Width="200" Height="30">Here is some very long sample text </Label>
  </Canvas>
</ContentControl>
<Slider Name="mySlider" Minimum="-200" Maximum="100" />
```